# Why Facebook preview image is not showing up in post but visible in debug tool?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to post some jobs on facebook but Preview image is not showing for some job.

Image shows up on posting [this](http://bevforce.com/jobs/regional-account-manager-1) link but when I post [this](http://bevforce.com/jobs/market-manager-washington-dc) link the preview image does not come.

When check both link in facebook developer [tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) both above link works fine and `og:image` comes for both link then why one of the [link](http://bevforce.com/jobs/market-manager-washington-dc) is not showing on actual post ?